# After inserting into MYSQL database, why is my scraped data not properly aligned in the right column?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a code to scrape data and insert it into MYSQL database, but the data wasn't inserted in the right columns in the database. It mixes up, like some rows in 'skills' being saved under 'company_name' column and vice versa. How do i make the different data to be saved under the appropriate columns respectively.

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import writer
import mysql.connector



db = mysql.connector.connect(host= 'localhost',
                         user= 'root',
                         password= 'Maxesafrica2')
     
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE jobberman_db")
print("Connection to MYSQL Established!")
db = mysql.connector.connect(host= 'localhost',
            user= 'root',
            password= 'Maxesafrica2',
            database = 'jobberman_db'
           )

print("Connected to Database!")
cursor = db.cursor()
mysql_create_table_query = """CREATE TABLE jobberman_tbl (company_name Varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
                                                   skills Varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
                                                   job_desc VarChar(3000),
                                                   job_link VarChar(3000),
                                                   salary_scale VarChar(3000))"""
                       
result = cursor.execute(mysql_create_table_query)


html_text = requests.get('https://www.jobberman.com/jobs/hospitality-leisure').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'mx-5 md:mx-0 flex flex-wrap col-span-1 mb-5 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 hover:border-gray-400 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-gray-500')


with open('jobberman.csv', 'w+', newline = '',  encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     header = ['company name', 'skills', 'job desc', 'job link', 'salary scale']
     writer = csv.writer(f)      
     writer.writerow(header)


     salary_scale = ''

     job_list = []
     for job in jobs:
         company_name = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-sm text-brand-linked').text
         skills = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-lg font-medium break-words text-brand-linked').text
         job_desc = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-sm font-normal text-gray-700 md:text-gray-500 md:pl-5').text
         job_link = job.a['href']
         salary_scale1 = job.find('span', class_ = 'mr-1')
        
         if salary_scale1:
            salary_scale = salary_scale1.text
         else:
            salary_scale = 'Not Mentioned'


         joblist = [company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale]
         writer.writerow(joblist)

             
         all_details = {company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale}
         all_details = tuple(all_details)
         job_list.append(all_details)

         insert_query = """INSERT INTO jobberman_tbl (company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale)
                         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
                         
         records_to_insert = job_list 

         db = mysql.connector.connect(host= 'localhost',
       user= 'root',
       password= 'Maxesafrica2',
       database = 'jobberman_db'
      )

         cursor = db.cursor()
         cursor.executemany(insert_query, records_to_insert)            
         db.commit()
         cursor.close()
         db.close()

         print('Done!')
```

Here is a picture from mysql database to illustrate what a talking about
[image: The picture shows that Data are not properly arranged in the table. Some 'salary scale' data being listed under 'skills' & 'company name' column and a host of others]

Comment: its probably your scraped data that is incorrect, why dont you log it before you save it so you have something to compare

Comment: Hi @Breezer thanks for replying. I was able to write it to a .CSV file but not with a different list. I made some edit to the code above please check. Do you think the problem is from `all_details = tuple(all_details)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment to job_link doesn't look right.  Try:

```
job_link = job.find("a", href=True)["href"]
```

Comment: Thanks @phatfingers for replying. This still gave me the job links but didn't solve the main issue. Do you think this tuple list is wrong `all_details = tuple(all_details)`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue corrected by changing `all_details = {company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale}` to `all_details = (company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale)`.

Thanks @Breezer and @phatfingers for the attempt. Much appreciated.
.